# Why Github PR does not show the changes merged by a PR from another branch?

Tags: git, github

I had the following branches on my git repo on Github:

- `trunk`
- `err_feedback_fixed`
- `err_feedback_evolve`

First, I merged `err_feedback_fixed` into `trunk`. Next, I created a pull request for merging `err_feedback_evolve` into `trunk`, as below.

[image]

I was reviewing the document on 'Files changed' tab. I realized that the file from `trunk` branch shown on the left of the screen does not include the commits I previously merged from `err_feedback_fixed` branch. For instance, after the first merge, the lines highlighted by red in the snapshot above have been changed to the following

```
from Optim_rule import my_optimizer_auto as OptimAdptAuto, my_optimizer, symmetric_rule, fixed_feedback
```

But I can't see this when comparing the files in the second merge. I was wondering what is the reason and how can I review with the most recent versions of the two codes in the 'Files changed' view? Here is the `trunk` branch on Github:

[image]

---

EDIT:

Upon further looking into the matter, it appears that this is an issue with Github: see [this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/pull-request-diff-does-not-update-when-a-commit-fr/51306). Is there any solution for this as of 2022?

Comment: Are you **sure** that change is present in the branch you think it's in? Is it possible that you have that change locally, but haven't pushed it? Because GitHub is simply showing you what it has. If the contents of the file aren't what you expect them to be, it's not a problem with GitHub, it's more likely a problem with how you're *using* GitHub.

Comment: @DanielMann I added a snapshot of the `main.py` on `trunk`.

Comment: @DanielMann This seems to be an actual problem with Github: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/pull-request-diff-does-not-update-when-a-commit-fr/51306.

Comment: That's *not* a GitHub issue -- it's an Azure DevOps issue. If you look at the dates, that predates Microsoft's acquisition of GitHub by several years.

Comment: @DanielMann I modified my question to add details. My current issue is similar to the one in the link anyways.